# Bluetooth mouse reconnection

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, 22.04, logitech, logitech-unifying

I have a Logitech M720 Triathlon that can change between computers, but whenever I try to change back to my Ubuntu, it will not connect. I have to connect manually on the bluetooth devices. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Ubuntu 22.04, Dell XPS 13

Comment: When you connect the mouse what does `dmesg` say? (about the bluetooth connection)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with my Bluetooth headset.

I use [bluetooth quick connect](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1401/bluetooth-quick-connect/) gnome extension to get around this issue.

Please make sure to change the settings in extensions for bluetooth quick connect as per the image provided. [bluetooth quick connect extension settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91HCE.png)

Please do comment if it worked and make sure to accept solution or upvote this answer if it works :)