# Shortcut and command to connect to specify bluetooth device

Tags: bash, gnome, bluetooth, mouse

My mouse switches between bluetooth computers. However, on Ubuntu, I have to reconnect to it with the other mouse by clicking on connect as below:

[image]

Is there a script that I can write that does this reconnection every 2 seconds, or when I do a key stroke? I already tried to find a solution here [Bluetooth mouse reconnection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411570/bluetooth-mouse-reconnection) but couldn't

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem. No real answer in the Internet, so I have been digging around the terminal. Here is what I came up with:

Connect your bluetooth device.

```
$ bluetoothctl info
```

This will show you the device, most importantly the name, which will be something like A4:B4:23:EE...

Then,create a desktop shortcut in the system settings -> keyboard -> custom shortcuts:

```
/usr/bin/bluetoothctl connect "A4:B4:23:EE..."
```